# IIf statement too complex

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, ms-access-2003

I am attempting quite a long IIf statement in MS Access 2003, but when I bolt bits on it's advising me its too complex:

```
MIN_PASS_FAIL: IIf(
  [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0033"
, "ACCEPTED"
, IIf(
    [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0037"
  , "ACCEPTED"
  , IIf(
      [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0038"
    , "ACCEPTED"
    , IIf(
        [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0039"
      , "ACCEPTED"
      , IIf(
          [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0040"
        , "ACCEPTED"
        , IIf(
            [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0055"
          , "ACCEPTED"
          , IIf(
              [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0056"
            , "ACCEPTED"
            , IIf(
                [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0061"
              , "ACCEPTED"
              , IIf(
                  [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0073"
                , "ACCEPTED"
                , Iif(
                    [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0013"
                  , "INFORMATION"
                  , Iif(
                      [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0018"
                    , "INFORMATION"
                    , Iif(
                        [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0019"
                      , "INFORMATION"
                      , Iif(
                          [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0028"
                        , "INFORMATION"
                        , Iif(
                            [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0045"
                          , "INFORMATION"
                          , Iif(
                              [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0046"
                            , "INFORMATION"
                            , Iif(
                                [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0047"
                              , "INFORMATION"
                              , Iif(
                                  [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0048"
                                , "INFORMATION"
                                , Iif(
                                    [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = "0060"
                                  , "INFORMATION"
                                  , "REJECTED"
                                  )
                                )
                              )
                            )
                          )
                        )
                      )
                    )
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I want three outputs, "Accepted" "Rejected" and "Information"..

How would I be able to resolve this?

Comment: Please format your code. It is unreadable.

Comment: pzanger - if i split on to seperate lines the dialog box advises this is too long??

Comment: I've formatted the code for Stack Overflow but obviously Access will mess up query formatting at the first opportunity. I've learned to store the text of the queries elsewhere and just create them in Access.

Answer (score 3):

You have one set of codes which map to *"ACCEPTED"*, and another set which maps to *"INFORMATION"*.  Any other code should map to *"REJECTED"*.

Use a table such as the one below to store the mappings for the first two sets.  You can then use `DLookup` to retrieve *response_text* values for codes in the first 2 sets.

```vb
DLookup("response_text", "YourTableNameHere", "response_code='" & [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] & "'")
```

For *"REJECTED"* codes, `DLookup` will return Null.  So you can use `Nz()` to substitute *"REJECTED"* for Null.

```vb
Nz(DLookup("response_text", "YourTableNameHere", "response_code='" & [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] & "'"), "REJECTED")
```

A similar approach should work in Access VBA code or in a query run from within an Access session.  If you will be using this in a query which will be run outside an Access session, you can use an `IIf` expression instead of `Nz`.

However, if this is for a query, consider left joining your main data table to the mapping table.  Then you wouldn't even need `DLookup`...

```sql
SELECT
    main.[MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE],
    Nz(ytnh.response_text, 'REJECTED') AS MIN_PASS_FAIL
FROM
    MainTable AS main
    LEFT JOIN YourTableNameHere AS ytnh
    ON main.[MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] = ytnh.response_code;
```

The mapping table ...

```
response_code response_text
0033          ACCEPTED
0037          ACCEPTED
0038          ACCEPTED
0039          ACCEPTED
0040          ACCEPTED
0055          ACCEPTED
0056          ACCEPTED
0061          ACCEPTED
0073          ACCEPTED
0013          INFORMATION
0018          INFORMATION
0019          INFORMATION
0028          INFORMATION
0045          INFORMATION
0046          INFORMATION
0047          INFORMATION
0048          INFORMATION
0060          INFORMATION
```

Comment: brill... that looks perfect... I will give that a go tonight when I get home.  Thank you soo much for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: Good suggestion. Alternatively to `DLookup`, you could you join with the lookup table in your query for better performance.

Comment: Right.  I didn't make that point clearly yesterday.  I added a query outline with a `LEFT JOIN` and `Nz()`.

Answer (score 2):

HansUp's answer to put it into lookup tables is good. Especially if they may change. For an answer that doesn't require lookup tables, you can use the InStr function. try this:

```
MIN_PASS_FAIL: IIF(InStr("0033.0037.0038.0039.0040.0055.0056",[MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE]),"ACCEPTED",IIf(InStr("0013.0018.0019.0028.0045.0046.0047.0048.0060",[MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE]),"ACCEPTED",IIf(InStr("0013.0018.0019.0028.0045.0046.0047.0048.0060",[MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE]),"INFORMATION","REJECTED")))
```

Comment: thanks tom, but that doesnt have 'information' for some of the error codes?

Answer (score 2):

HansUp's answer is definitely the best one since you have so many items to look up. I'll point out an alternative because it might be handy in other situations.

Since you're always testing the same field, you can use the SQL `in` operator:

```
MIN_PASS_FAIL: IIf(
  [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] in (
    "0033"
  , "0037"
  , "0038"
  , ...
  )
, "ACCEPTED"
, Iif(
    [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] in (
      "0013"
    , "0018"
    , "0019"
    , ...
    )
  , "INFORMATION"
  , "REJECTED"
  )
)
```

The `in` operator tests if the value is one out of a list of values. This keeps your code relatively flat. In fact, you can flatten it completely by using the `Switch` function instead of the `Iif` function:

```
MIN_PASS_FAIL: Switch(
  [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] in (
    "0033"
  , "0037"
  , "0038"
  , ...
  )
, "ACCEPTED"
, [MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE] in (
    "0013"
  , "0018"
  , "0019"
  , ...
  )
, "INFORMATION"
, True
, "REJECTED"
)
```

You can look up details on the `Switch` function easily enough, but basically it works like a `case` statement or `switch` statement in other languages, but SQL is conveniently expression-oriented so you're always returning a value.

Comment: +1 for the switch idea. A little neater code since it doesn't rely on nested IIF.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function in visual basic and then call it from the query. Much faster than a table lookup.
MIN_PASS_FAIL: GetResponseStatus([MIN CAR RESPONSE CODE])